# Apache flink pattern conditions with list

Tags: java, apache-flink, complex-event-processing

I wrote a pattern. I have a list for conditions(gettin rules from json).Data(json) is coming form kafka server . I want to filter the data with this list. But it is not working. How can I do that? 
I am not sure about keyedstream and alarms in for. Can flink work like this?

main program:

```
package cep_kafka_eample.cep_kafka;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import org.apache.flink.cep.CEP;
import org.apache.flink.cep.PatternSelectFunction;
import org.apache.flink.cep.PatternStream;
import org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.Pattern;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.SlidingProcessingTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.JSONDeserializationSchema;
import util.AlarmPatterns;
import util.Rules;
import util.TypeProperties;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {

        ObjectMapper mapper    = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                "c://new 5.json"));
        JsonArray array = (JsonArray)obj;
        Gson googleJson = new Gson();
        List<Rules> ruleList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i< array.size() ; i++) {
            Rules jsonObjList = googleJson.fromJson(array.get(i), Rules.class);
            ruleList.add(jsonObjList);
        }

        //apache kafka properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

        //starting flink
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.enableCheckpointing(1000).setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        //get kafka values
        FlinkKafkaConsumer010<ObjectNode> myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>("demo", new JSONDeserializationSchema(),
                properties);
        List<Pattern<ObjectNode,?>> patternList = new ArrayList<>();
        DataStream<ObjectNode> dataStream = env.addSource(myConsumer);
        dataStream.windowAll(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10), Time.seconds(5)));
        DataStream<ObjectNode> keyedStream = dataStream;
        //get pattern list, keyeddatastream
        for(Rules rules : ruleList){
            List<TypeProperties> typePropertiesList = rules.getTypePropList();
            for (int i = 0; i < typePropertiesList.size(); i++) {
                TypeProperties typeProperty = typePropertiesList.get(i);
                if (typeProperty.getGroupType() != null && typeProperty.getGroupType().equals("group")) {
                    keyedStream = keyedStream.keyBy(
                            jsonNode -> jsonNode.get(typeProperty.getPropName().toString())
                    );
                }
            }
            Pattern<ObjectNode,?> pattern = new AlarmPatterns().getAlarmPattern(rules);
            patternList.add(pattern);
        }
        //CEP pattern and alarms
        List<DataStream<Alert>> alertList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Pattern<ObjectNode,?> pattern : patternList){
            PatternStream<ObjectNode> patternStream = CEP.pattern(keyedStream, pattern);
            DataStream<Alert> alarms = patternStream.select(new PatternSelectFunction<ObjectNode, Alert>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                public Alert select(Map<String, List<ObjectNode>> map) throws Exception {
                    return new Alert("new message");
                }
            });
            alertList.add(alarms);
        }
        env.execute("Flink CEP monitoring job");
    }
}
```

getAlarmPattern:

```
  package util;

import org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.Pattern;
import org.apache.flink.cep.pattern.conditions.IterativeCondition;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class AlarmPatterns {

    public Pattern<ObjectNode, ?> getAlarmPattern(Rules rules) {

        //MySimpleConditions conditions = new MySimpleConditions();
      Pattern<ObjectNode, ?>  alarmPattern = Pattern.<ObjectNode>begin("first")
                .where(new IterativeCondition<ObjectNode>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(ObjectNode jsonNodes, Context<ObjectNode> context) throws Exception {
                        for (Criterias criterias : rules.getCriteriaList()) {
                            if (criterias.getCriteriaType().equals("equals")) {
                                return jsonNodes.get(criterias.getPropName()).equals(criterias.getCriteriaValue());
                            } else if (criterias.getCriteriaType().equals("greaterThen")) {
                                if (!jsonNodes.get(criterias.getPropName()).equals(criterias.getCriteriaValue())) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                int count = 0;
                                for (ObjectNode node : context.getEventsForPattern("first")) {
                                    count += node.get("value").asInt();
                                }
                                return Integer.compare(count, 5) > 0;
                            } else if (criterias.getCriteriaType().equals("lessThen")) {
                                if (!jsonNodes.get(criterias.getPropName()).equals(criterias.getCriteriaValue())) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                int count = 0;
                                for (ObjectNode node : context.getEventsForPattern("first")) {
                                    count += node.get("value").asInt();
                                }
                                return Integer.compare(count, 5) < 0;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }).times(rules.getRuleCount());
        return alarmPattern;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your problem?  What specifically is "not working" with filtering?  What output are you expecting for a given input?

Comment: When i debug pattern, debugger is not coming to filter function. Isn't it? What do you think?

Comment: how do you apply the pattern to your stream? what are the input elements in the stream? Are you sure there are any?

Comment: Do you call `execute` on your `ExecutionEnvironment`? Do you work in `EventTime` Could you post whole main method of your job?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using FlinkCEP!

Could you provide some more details about what exactly is the error message (if any)? This will help a lot at pinning down the problem.

From a first look at the code, I can make the following observations:

At first, the line:

`dataStream.windowAll(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10), Time.seconds(5)));`

will never be executed, as you never use this stream in the rest of your program.

Second, you should specify a sink to be taken after the `select()`, e.g. `print()` method on each of your `PatternStream`s. If you do not do so, then your output gets discarded. You can have a look [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sinks) for examples, although the list is far from exhaustive.

Finally, I would recommend adding a `within()` clause to your pattern, so that you do not run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for aswer Kostas. I couldn't understand why i can't use slidingprocessingtimewindows? I will use print and within then i will write new post

Answer (score 0):

Error was from my json object. I will fix it. When i am run job on intellij cep doesn't work. When submit from flink console it works.